# Promise отработал. А как мне получить от него результат?

Tags: javascript, promise

В проекте подключается Dropbox SDK, который предоставляет возможность работать с API Dropbox'а и целиком и полностью основан на промисах.

Я пытаюсь получить содержимое корневой директории. Для этого вызываю метод `filesListFolder`, который, насколько я понимаю, возвращает промис (решил я так потому, что на ответе можно вызвать метод `then`). Ну, собственно, этот метод я и вызываю, теперь внутри мне действительно доступен интересующий меня объект со списком всего, что есть в рутовой директории.

```
let rootDirContents = DBI.filesListFolder({
    path: ""
}).then(ans => {
    return ans
});

console.dir(rootDirContents);
```

Но как мне вытащить этот объект `ans` "на поверхность"? Как мне записать его  в переменную rootDirContents? Потому что сейчас туда записывается еще один промис, что в принципе, логично, поскольку метод `then`, насколько я знаю, всегда возвращает тоже промис.

Так вот как мне сделать так, чтобы в переменную `rootDirContents` записалось именно содержимое `ans`, а не новый промис, с которым я понятия не имею, что делать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88405/discussion-on-question-by-smellyshovel-promise------).